# Error consuming web service due to content type of application/dime (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to consume a 3rd party web service using ASP.Net which is generating the following error message:

> Message=The content type application/dime of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly.

I am able to connect to the service and access on one of available operations successfully. However, when trying to use another operation I receive the above error message. I am using .Net 4.0. The 3rd party service is written in .Net, though I am not sure of the version, etc.

I have read that the application/dime type is no longer supported, but is there a way that I can use this web service with .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an old link with some tips in it at: http://www.ureader.com/msg/1438351.aspx

> after adding a Web reference to the DIME-based Web service, you must 
>   modify
>   the proxy class in the References.cs file so that it inherits from the
>   Microsoft.Web.Services.WebServicesClientProtocol class in WSE.
>   For example, the client Web service proxy generated for the ImageService 
>   Web
>   service from the previous example needs to be modified as follows:
>
> `public class ImageService : Microsoft.Web.Services.WebServicesClientProtocol`

Does that help you get something working?